# Storybook web-components: sending array as component property

Tags: javascript, web-component, storybook, stenciljs

I'm using Storybook 6.5.9 to render web components (made with Stencil). I have several of them working correctly but now I'm creating a story for a new component that can receive a property that is an array of objects.

The component would be something like this:

```
import {Component, Host, h, Prop} from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'test-component',
})

export class TestComponent {
  /**
   * Array of options for the group.
   */
  @Prop() items?: String[] = [];

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        {
          this.items.map(item => (
            <h1>{item}</h1>
          ))
        }
      </Host>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the story:

```
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/html';

export default {
  title: 'Components/TestComponent',
  parameters: {
    options: {
      showPanel: true
    },
  }
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => {
  return `
    <test-component items="${['some', 'thing']}">
    </test-component>
  `;
};

export const TestComponent: Story = Template.bind({});
```

I have tried setting the `items` property to a string but the component never gets anything, it's always an empty array.

I'm not getting any errors either in the console. I'm definitely doing something wrong but I don't know what it is... I've been using several other data types for those properties (boolean, string, numbers...) but this is the first time I'm using objects/arrays and I'm not able to get it to work.

Any help will be highly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are passed in as strings in HTML.

Use `JSON.parse(this.items)` in your `render()` method in case `this.items` is not an `array`:

```js
import { Component, Host, h, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
})
export class MyComponent {
  /**
   * Array of options for the group.
   */
  @Prop() items?: string | string[] = '';

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        {(Array.isArray(this.items) ? this.items : JSON.parse(this.items)).map(item => (
          <h1>{item}</h1>
        ))}
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

For that to work, you need to pass in your `items` as valid JSON, meaning you have to use single attribute quotes and double quotes for the "strings" in the "array":

```
const Template: Story = (args) => `
    <test-component items='${["some", "thing"]}'>
    </test-component>
`;
```

If you are receiving `[object Object]` in your component, try to stringify your prop value before passing:

```
const Template: Story = (args) => `
    <test-component items='${JSON.stringify(["some", "thing"])}'>
    </test-component>
`;
```

Comment: thanks! that helps. But the string I'm receiving in the component is `"some,thing"` so the `JSON.parse` part is not working as expected. For some reason the array brackets are not being received properly.

Also, if I send a more complex array structure, like an array of objects, what I received in the component is something like `"[object Object],[object Object]"` instead of the full content.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Added info on that at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set arrays or objects as properties via HTML (only in JSX/TSX). You have two options:

1. pass them as a JSON string and parse them back into an array/object; you’d basically have to type them as a string in your component, and then cast the type after parsing them
2. set the property via a script; there’s two options, depending on whether or not the option is required or not.

```html
<test-component></test-component>

<script>
  document.querySelector("test-component").items = ["foo"]
</script>
```

or if the prop is required:

```html
<script>
  const testComponent = document.createElement("test-component")

  testComponent.items = ["foo"]

  document.body.appendChild(testComponent)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

That would be an option. In fact, in Storybook 6.1 I can use something similar by importing the `object` method from `'@storybook/addon-knobs'` and then setting the property like `testComponent.items = object('Items', items);` and this works all fine.

But this is deprecated in the new versions of Storybook so I have to find a proper way of doing it.

Comment: Looks like you can do it with controls with custom args? https://storybook.js.org/docs/web-components/essentials/controls, scroll down to “fully custom args”. I don’t have too much experience with Storybook though.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of these solutions to work for me however it looks like Storybook has now made it easier. I'm not sure what version it was introduced in but upgrade this package to:

`"@storybook/angular": "7.6.17",`

You will now have access to the new function argsToTemplate. Docs can be found here:

https://storybook.js.org/docs/essentials/controls#fully-custom-args

Here's an example where I needed to pass data to the ng-content in the component. All the arguments will be assigned to the component:

```
import {  argsToTemplate } from '@storybook/angular';
export const ComponentStory: Story = {
  args: {
    ...Default.args,
   // Additional args if needed
  },
  render: (args) => {
    return {
      props: args,
      template: `
        <component-name ${argsToTemplate(args)}>
          Actions
        </component-name>
      `,
    };
  },
};
```